# Идентификатор для спецсимволов в HTML5

Tags: html, css, html5

Мне нужно отредактировать спецсимволы на своей странице, но я не знаю как присвоить им id для дальнейшего редактирования символа в `CSS`. Каким способом это можно сделать? Например, как это делать с тегами я понимаю, а как со спецсимволами нет. И, если использовать теги `div`, то будет ли это правильно?

Comment: к символам нет привязки, только к dom элементам

Comment: спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, зачем в принципе может понадобиться "редактировать спецсимволы в css"? И какой вообще смысл вы вкладываете в эту фразу?